# Django merge querysets in one page

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-forms, pagination, django-queryset

In django rest framework i am using pagination of 20 on a model.
Now i want to make a queryset which takes 5 items which has the featured field as true.
The other 15 should be items which has the featured field as false.

Does anyone have an idea how to make this work?

```
permission_classes = [AllowAny]
serializer_class = JobSerializer
pagination_class = Pagination

order_types = {
    1: 'job_order', #by randomized job order
    2: '-created_date', #newest to oldest
    3: 'created_date', #oldest to newest
    4: 'name', #by name A -> Z,
    5: '-name' #by name Z -> A,
}

def get_queryset(self):
 
    requirements = self.request.query_params.getlist('requirements', None)
    order_param = self.request.query_params.get('order_by', 1)

    #make querysets
    queryset_featured = Job.objects.all().filter(active=True, featured=True).order_by(self.order_types[int(order_param)])
    queryset_non_featured = Job.objects.all().filter(active=True, featured=False).order_by(self.order_types[int(order_param)])
    
   
    return queryset.distinct()
```

Comment: You just want to sort by the ones that have featured?

Comment: @JamesLin I want to make 2 querysets, 1 with featured and 1 without. Every page of 20 i want to have 5 off the featured and the other 15 off none featured

Answer (score 3):

Use a union of two separate queries:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#union

This will allow you to make one ORM query for the featured items with `[0:5]`, and then union to an ORM query for non-featured items with `[0:15]`.

I haven't tested this, but here's an example with your code:

```py
queryset_featured = Job.objects.all().filter(active=True, featured=True).order_by(self.order_types[int(order_param)])[0:5]
queryset_non_featured = Job.objects.all().filter(active=True, featured=False).order_by(self.order_types[int(order_param)])[0:15]
queryset_combined = queryset_featured.union(queryset_non_featured)

for row in queryset_combined:
    print(row)
```

Comment: I find it hard to understand how i can make this with my own code: added it above here.
Could you give me an sample of what i have to edit in my code?

Comment: Tried it but it does not work. Still getting a mix of both... while i would like to have first 5 featured rest of it none featured for every page

Comment: I'd take a look at the results of all three querysets (`queryset_featured`, `queryset_non_featured`, and `queryset_combined`) individually at the command line as a next step. Hopefully that'll offer a clue as to where the problem lies.

Comment: @FlipperPA I think he wants every page to display 5 featured and 15 unfeatured, but somehow as whole to be paginated.

Comment: @FlipperPA that is what i want, but i cant seem to make it work